# error: expected expression before ‘float’

Tags: c

I would like to find all the primes within 100. Here is my codes.

```
// Find all the prime number within 100.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int main() {
   int i,n;
   int j = 0;
   for ( n = 2; n <= 100; ++n) {
      bool isPrime = true;
      for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(float(n)); ++i) {
         if(n % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;  
            break;
         }
      }
      if(isPrime) {
         ++j;
         printf("%d is a prime number\n",n);
      }
  }
  printf("The total number of prime number within 100 is %d\n",j);
  return 0;
```

}

When compile it, there is one error.

```
prime.c:14:8: error: expected expression before ‘float’
m = float(n);
    ^
```

Could anyone help solve this problem？ Thanks.

Comment: What is `float(n)` is C? Just pass `n`.

Comment: Note: `sqrt()` precision is not specified by C and weak `sqrt()` routines may return a value just below a whole number - invalidating the `i <= sqrt(float(n))` logic.  A quick fix is `i*i <= n`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax when casting (you're using one of C++'s many styles of casting, but for C there is only one way). Change:

```
sqrt(float(n))
```

to

```
sqrt((float)n)
```

Note however that `sqrt` takes a `double`, so strictly speaking this should be:

```
sqrt((double)n)
```

Note also that the cast is not necessary, and you can just write:

```
sqrt(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this

`sqrt(float(n))`

to this

`sqrt((float)n)`

You want to cast `n` to float.

You should use this function:

`float sqrtf (float x);`

which in C99 receives a float as an argument. Otherwise, it would be better to cast into double (if you use sqrt()).

[sqrt-ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/)

What you have written:

`float(n)`

is like saying that float is a name of a function and you pass to it the parameter n.

Notice, that in your case, you don't need casting, since it's going to be performed automatically (to float if you use sqrtf() or to double if you use sqrt()).

---

Other notes, irrelevant with your syntax error.

Why not start the loop from 3 and increase the counter by two? If you think about it, this will faster and will produce the same results. If you want to test yourself, check my example [here](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/isprime-c/).

Also, what I had found pretty exciting when I was searching for primes, is the sieve of Eratosthene's (Κόσκινο του Ερατοσθένη) . [Here is](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/eratostheness-sieve-c/) an example of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cast `n` to a `float`, use `(float)n`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
sqrt(n);
```

You'll be having the exam same result as the casting for your case.